# Eclipse - java smart editor not activated by default

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I have a problem with my Eclipse installation. I've recently perfomed some updates on it(most notably I've installed a bundle of plugins, I don't remember the complete list but for sure I've installed the code checkers Findbugs, PMD and Checkstyle). But now, when I try to open a Java file by double clicking it on any Explorer View(be it Package Explorer, Project Explorer, Navigator etc) it is not opened using the usual Java smart editor, but via a weird editor somewhere between the Java editor and the Text editor. In particular, the in-class navigation operations(like Ctrl + o - Open Member) work as expected, however inter-class navigation(like for instance F3 - Open Declaration) does not work. I get an error message "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project".

However, if I open the class via the Open Type menu(Ctrl + Shift + t) I get the full-blown Java smart editor with all functionality working as expected.

Then, if I try to open the Java class file by navigating to it in the Explorer view then right clicking and selecting Open With -> Java Editor, I get the same weird editor and not the Java smart editor.

I tried uninstalling the code checker plugins: Findbugs, PMD, Checkstyle, but to no avail.

I don't know exactly where/how this behaviour is triggered, and what puzzles me is that it works with Open Type but not via double cliking or context menu. I've taken a look over the Eclipse logs too, but I don't see any information relevant for this behaviour. And since I'm no expert in Eclipse internals, I ask you this question...

Best regards,
Florin.

Comment: Did you try the "Open With > Default Editor" context-menu option?

Comment: yep, opens up the same weird editor

Answer (score 2):

Try re-setting the default editor for Java files by going to `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`

Here is how mine is setup :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, I have 3 entries for .java files: GWT Java Editor(even thought I uninstalled GWT plugin meanwhile...hm) then second comes Java Editor, then third Text Editor. But unfortunately I cannot edit/remove any of these! Same if I go to 'Content Types', Java Source File is locked...

Comment: Try clicking on `Java Editor` and then click on Default. After you do that what happens when you try to open a Java file (try with something you did not do an `Open With` before)

Comment: @Florin, Create a new Java class. Close it and then re-open it. Is the problem present even while opening this file ?

Comment: After I made the `Java Editor` the default, per @Ashutosh's comment, I had to create an error in the file, open the file by double-clicking the error in the Problems tab (which forced Eclipse to open the file using the `Java Editor`), leave the file open, close and restart Eclipse. Then My file association was finally fixed. As @Rori pointed out in his answer, this problem started after I installed the Google GWT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem - there is some editor conflict caused by Google's Plugin for Eclipse. Uninstalling all of Google's GPE & SDK packages fixed the problem. I don't have a solution yet.